# How do we take care of the case illustrated in figure 3.8?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

[image]

Consider figure 3.8, if we pick $k$ to be the lowest point between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ as in the illustration, then it is not the case that $f(x_1) - k < 0$ and $f(x_2) - k > 0$. Why does the proof still work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are picking $k$ between the $y$-values $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.  That is not the same as picking an arbitrary $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and setting $k = f(x)$.  Not every $x\in [x_1,x_2]$ necessarily corresponds to a value of $f(x)$ such that $f(x) \in [f(x_1),f(x_2)]$.

See the image below: the "lowest point" is not a valid choice of $k$, so there is no issue with the proof.

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that $f(x_1) < k < f(x_2)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what is meant by the statement "let $k$ be any value between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$."  Note that $f(x_1) < k < f(x_2) \implies f(x_1) - k < 0 < f(x_2) - k$.

Comment: But then how we deal with figure 3.8, as I wrote?

Comment: Can you indicate on the image what you mean by "lowest point?" Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: There is a clear dip in figure 3.8 which is lower than both $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$. I mean, what happens if we pick k to be that value?

Comment: That's my point.  $k$, as specified in the proof, *can't* be chosen to be that dip because then you would be picking $k < f(x_1)$ instead of $f(x_1) < k$.

Comment: Right, so why does the proof work?

Comment: Because they *specifically exclude that possibility*.  I'm not sure what else to say.  The proof specifies that $f(x_1) < k < f(x_2)$.  That means that $k$ *cannot be chosen* the way you are asking.  You are correct in saying you've found a value of $k$ for which the proof wouldn't work, but that case has been excluded by assumption.

Comment: But the IVT still holds even if we have such a case, so why does the theorem work?!?!?

Comment: @politeproofs I added an image to my answer - does that clear up why your choice of $k$ isn't valid?

Comment: Yes, your image makes sense, but what is unclear to me is that IVT can still be used even if we pick the dot outside the range, right?

Comment: The IVT only guarantees that the function will attain every value along the red line.  It doesn't guarantee that the function will hit the low point unless that point is chosen as either $x_1$ or $x_2$, in which case the range for $k$ is wider.

Comment: I see, then I misunderstood the original theorem. Thanks for bearing with my confusion, I've upvoted and accepted your answer.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!